# How can I clean up my ggplot geom_tile? How do I with create a legend and edit my label locations?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-tile

would like to:
add a legend for the fill,
move my axis labels and title,
use specific colors for the three fill values

Code below

#adding data and libraries

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(plotly)
    library(here)
    library(dplyr)
    trails = read.csv("../input/national-park-trails/AllTrails data -nationalpark.csv")
    summary(trails)
    head(trails)
```

#subsets

```
    ca_trails = trails %>% filter(state_name=="California") #filter data set to CA
    JT_trails = ca_trails %>% filter(area_name=="Joshua Tree National 
Park") #filter set to JT

    head(JT_trails)
```

#ggplot

```
    JT_trailgraph <- ggplot(JT_trails, aes(x=difficulty_rating, y=name)) +
       geom_tile(aes(fill = visitor_usage)) +
       labs(title = "Joshua Tree Trails", subtitle = "Difficulty Rating Compared to Usage",
       y = "Name", x = "Difficulty Rating") 

    ggplotly(JT_trailgraph, width = 700, height = 1500)
```

```
    dput(head(JT_trails)
```

```
structure(list(trail_id = c(10011170L, 10031888L, 10035554L, 
10003872L, 10019827L, 10034036L), name = c("Ryan Mountain Trail", 
"Barker Dam Nature Trail", "Hidden Valley Nature Trail", "Lost Palms Oasis", 
"Arch Rock Nature Trail", "Fortynine Palms Oasis Trail"), area_name = c("Joshua Tree National Park", 
"Joshua Tree National Park", "Joshua Tree National Park", "Joshua Tree National Park", 
"Joshua Tree National Park", "Joshua Tree National Park"), city_name = c("Twentynine Palms", 
"Twentynine Palms", "Twentynine Palms", "Indio", "Twentynine Palms", 
"Twentynine Palms"), state_name = c("California", "California", 
"California", "California", "California", "California"), country_name = c("United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States"), X_geoloc = c("{'lat': 34.00264, 'lng': -116.13594}", 
"{'lat': 34.02511, 'lng': -116.14173}", "{'lat': 34.01234, 'lng': -116.16807}", 
"{'lat': 33.73685, 'lng': -115.81058}", "{'lat': 33.984140000000004, 'lng': -116.01655}", 
"{'lat': 34.11922, 'lng': -116.11198}"), popularity = c(37.0218, 
30.1796, 27.9587, 26.1245, 24.81, 24.2376), length = c(4828.02, 
2896.812, 1609.34, 11587.248, 1126.538, 4506.152), elevation_gain = c(325.8312, 
19.812, 34.7472, 312.7248, 7.9248, 188.976), difficulty_rating = c(3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L), route_type = c("out and back", "out and back", 
"loop", "out and back", "out and back", "out and back"), visitor_usage = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L), avg_rating = c(4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 
4.5), num_reviews = c(917L, 480L, 500L, 295L, 251L, 381L), features = c("['dogs-no', 'kids', 'views', 'wild-flowers', 'wildlife']", 
"['dogs-no', 'forest', 'lake', 'kids', 'views', 'wild-flowers', 'wildlife']", 
"['dogs-no', 'kids', 'views', 'wild-flowers', 'wildlife']", "['dogs-no', 'views', 'wild-flowers', 'wildlife']", 
"['dogs-no', 'kids', 'views', 'wild-flowers', 'wildlife']", "['dogs-no', 'kids', 'views', 'wildlife']"
), activities = c("['hiking']", "['birding', 'hiking', 'nature-trips', 'rock-climbing', 'trail-running', 'walking']", 
"['birding', 'hiking', 'nature-trips', 'rock-climbing', 'trail-running', 'walking']", 
"['birding', 'hiking', 'nature-trips', 'rock-climbing', 'trail-running']", 
"['birding', 'camping', 'hiking', 'nature-trips', 'walking']", 
"['hiking', 'nature-trips', 'trail-running']"), units = c("i", 
"i", "i", "i", "i", "i")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

finally got to editing but stack wants me to write more words..... so I am adding more words to my post -_-
even more words are needed. I shall add more.

Comment: Could you please paste the output of `dput(head(JT_trails))` into the question to make the question reproducible?

Comment: I'm getting a server error when trying to add to my post...

Comment: I got dput inputted into my post

Answer (score 0):

The question does not state the expected position of the titles or axis labels.
So I've shown them moved: adjust to suit your preferred position.

Visitor usage is assumed to be one of three values: 1:3; I've manually added a 1L to the data so that the graph displays all three cases.
Again adjust colours and labelling to suit your own requirements.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(JT_trails, aes(x=difficulty_rating, y=name)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = factor(visitor_usage))) +
    scale_fill_manual(breaks = factor(1:3),
                      values = c("red", "blue", "green"),
                      labels = c("High", "Moderate", "Low"))+
  labs(title = "Joshua Tree Trails", 
       subtitle = "Difficulty Rating Compared to Usage",
       y = "Name", 
       x = "Difficulty Rating",
       fill = "Visitor usage") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 1),
        axis.title.x = element_text(hjust = 1),
        axis.title.y = element_text(hjust = 0))
```

data

```
JT_trails <- structure(list(trail_id = c(10011170L, 10031888L, 10035554L, 
                            10003872L, 10019827L, 10034036L), 
               name = c("Ryan Mountain Trail", "Barker Dam Nature Trail", "Hidden Valley Nature Trail", "Lost Palms Oasis", 
               "Arch Rock Nature Trail", "Fortynine Palms Oasis Trail"), 
               area_name = c("Joshua Tree National Park", 
              "Joshua Tree National Park", "Joshua Tree National Park", "Joshua Tree National Park", 
              "Joshua Tree National Park", "Joshua Tree National Park"), city_name = c("Twentynine Palms", 
 "Twentynine Palms", "Twentynine Palms", "Indio", "Twentynine Palms", 
 "Twentynine Palms"), state_name = c("California", "California", 
                                     "California", "California", "California", "California"), country_name = c("United States", 
                         "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
                         "United States"), X_geoloc = c("{'lat': 34.00264, 'lng': -116.13594}", 
             "{'lat': 34.02511, 'lng': -116.14173}", "{'lat': 34.01234, 'lng': -116.16807}", 
             "{'lat': 33.73685, 'lng': -115.81058}", "{'lat': 33.984140000000004, 'lng': -116.01655}", 
             "{'lat': 34.11922, 'lng': -116.11198}"), popularity = c(37.0218, 
                          30.1796, 27.9587, 26.1245, 24.81, 24.2376), length = c(4828.02, 
                                      2896.812, 1609.34, 11587.248, 1126.538, 4506.152), elevation_gain = c(325.8312, 
                      19.812, 34.7472, 312.7248, 7.9248, 188.976), difficulty_rating = c(3L, 
   1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L), route_type = c("out and back", "out and back", 
                                       "loop", "out and back", "out and back", "out and back"), visitor_usage = c(3L, 
                            3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L), avg_rating = c(4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 
                     4.5), num_reviews = c(917L, 480L, 500L, 295L, 251L, 381L), features = c("['dogs-no', 'kids', 'views', 'wild-flowers', 'wildlife']", 
       "['dogs-no', 'forest', 'lake', 'kids', 'views', 'wild-flowers', 'wildlife']", 
       "['dogs-no', 'kids', 'views', 'wild-flowers', 'wildlife']", "['dogs-no', 'views', 'wild-flowers', 'wildlife']", 
       "['dogs-no', 'kids', 'views', 'wild-flowers', 'wildlife']", "['dogs-no', 'kids', 'views', 'wildlife']"
                     ), activities = c("['hiking']", "['birding', 'hiking', 'nature-trips', 'rock-climbing', 'trail-running', 'walking']", 
                                       "['birding', 'hiking', 'nature-trips', 'rock-climbing', 'trail-running', 'walking']", 
                                       "['birding', 'hiking', 'nature-trips', 'rock-climbing', 'trail-running']", 
                                       "['birding', 'camping', 'hiking', 'nature-trips', 'walking']", 
                                       "['hiking', 'nature-trips', 'trail-running']"), units = c("i", 
           "i", "i", "i", "i", "i")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is amazing thank you so much for the help. Which part of the code added the legend into it. I see how you were able to adjust it, was that all it needed to make it pop up?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why your code did not display the legend: the legend appeared when I ran your code (as in the question) in the default location (on the left hand side of the plot) but the key was for a continuous fill variable, hence the need to convert to a factor.